# FB user with 2 ad accounts, but the AdUser can't see it

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm using Ads Api with this call in order to get the ad accounts:

`me/?fields=adaccounts`

I see one account with this result:

`{"adaccounts": {"data": [{"account_id": "1234567", "id": "act_1234567"}], 
"paging": {"cursors": {"after": "NjAxNDA2OTk5Mzg3Ng==", "before": "NjAxNDA2OTk5Mzg3Ng=="
}}}, 
"id": "111111"}`

But, when our client uses ads manager he can see two accounts. The one from this result and another one.
Our client told me that this user has advertising permissions to the second account.

How can it be? am I missing something? why can't I see both adaccounts?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you definitely using an access token from the very same User ID that the client is logging in as?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, when we generated a new Access Token for this user the problem solved and we were able to see the second ad account.